# Why is Euler's statement $\exp{(A + \frac{1}{2}B + \frac{1}{3}C+ \ldots)} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots$ true?

Tags: calculus, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, euler-product

Euler, in his paper *Variae observationes circa series infinitas* [[src]](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/72/), makes the following statements in his Theorem 19.

$$ \exp{(A + \frac{1}{2}B + \frac{1}{3}C+ \frac{1}{4}D + \ldots)} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}+ \dots $$

Where he defines:

$$A = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \dots $$
$$B = \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{5^2} + \frac{1}{7^2} + \dots $$
$$C = \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{5^3} + \frac{1}{7^3} + \dots $$

**Question:** I can't see how that statement is true.

I would appreciate replies that don't assume university level training in mathematics.

Comment: Well $A = \infty$, so the equation is $\exp(\infty) = \infty$.  Is $5$ really repeated in $A,B,C$?

Comment: Have you typed this correctly?  Why are the $5's$ (but no other denominator) repeated?  I assume you just meant to have the primes...

Comment: Assuming that the sums are meant to just cover the primes, with no repetition, then this follows by taking $s\to 1^+$ in the [Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product) for the Riemann zeta function.  Keep in mind that Euler did not distinguish between convergent and divergent series quite as religiously as we do.

Comment: Should say:  I don't see an entirely elementary way to see this.  At a minimum, you need to be familiar with the Taylor expansion of logs and you have to be comfortable with manipulating infinite sums and producs.

Comment: I didn't look at the original latin text but it is well-known that Euler totally messed up about the asymptotic of $\sum_{p\le x} 1/p$ compared to the harmonic numbers (that's why $\sum_{p\le x}1/p\sim \log \log x$ is called Mertens theorem). So it is plausible that he wrote the theorem 19 you are quoting, which is a nonsense (away from $\exp(\infty)=\infty$). That's what you get when looking at the prehistory of maths.

Comment: corrected the repeated 1/5 term.

Comment: Thanks for the comments re A being divergent. I am seeking insight into what Euler was trying to do, given he was a talented and insightful mathematician. In particular I am intrude by the pattern A+1/2B+1/3C ...

Comment: But that's just what you get by expanding the log.  we have  $\log \left(1-p^{-s}\right) =\sum \frac 1{np^{ns}}$ after all. This makes complete sense for $s>1$ (or even $Re(s)>1$), though of course passing to the limit as $s\to 1^+$ is something we'd want to analyze a bit more than Euler cared to.

Comment: Does the series $ 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{5} + \cdots $ converges

Answer (score 5):

It can be shown that
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^s }}} & = \prod\limits_p {\frac{1}{{1 - \frac{1}{{p^s }}}}}  = \exp \left( { - \sum\limits_p {\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{p^s }}} \right)} } \right) \\ &= \exp \left( {\sum\limits_p {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{np^{ns} }}} } } \right)=
\exp \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} {\sum\limits_p {\frac{1}{{p^{ns} }}} } } \right),
\end{align*}
whenever $\Re s>1$. Taking the limit $s\to 1+$ yields Euler's *formal* identity. I say formal, because the expressions on both sides will diverge. Note that I am not making an attempt to describe this in terms of non-university level mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, why don't you view it like this
$$ \exp{(A + \frac{1}{2}B + \frac{1}{3}C+ \frac{1}{4}D + \ldots)} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}+ \dots $$

Where $$A = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \dots $$
$$B = \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{5^2} + \frac{1}{7^2} + \dots $$
$$C = \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{5^3} + \frac{1}{7^3} + \dots $$
But this in terms of a function also say $p(n)$ is the function of the $n$th prime
$$ \exp[ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty } ( \frac{1}{k} \cdot    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ( \frac{1}{p(n)^k}  ) )] = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}  ( \frac{1}{n} ) $$

Comment: In the question, the sum of prime powers is multiplied by $1/k$ and not $1/p(k)$. Also your statement cannot be true, take for example $x=1$. The two sides will not be equal.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that

Comment: That's because $x$ is infinity, I just replaced $x$ with $\infty$